# Assign Sql Query Result To Variable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, variables

I have a MySql database and I want to assign sql query result to a variable. How can I do this?

My query:

```
sql = "SELECT rol FROM users WHERE user = '" + txtUser.Text + "'"
```

Comment: Start reading about ADO.NET. Also google for *'query database with C#'*

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Yes. Other than the OP you are not Lazy anymore!

Comment: Out of topic, but you should try to find something about SQL Injections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void AssignValue()
{
    using(MySqlConnection con =new MySqlConnection("/*connection string here*/"))
    using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT rol FROM users WHERE 
                                 user = @user",con))
    {
      con.Open();
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",txtUser.Text);        
      TextBox2.Text = commad.ExecuteScalar().ToString();        
    }
}
```

Comment: The command parameters are a good point. Better enclose the connection in a `using` statement. This ensures that it will be closed, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Error 1 The name 'roleName' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user3421239: are you able to run it now?